# addClass Jquery li

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a total newbie. I'm trying to add a class whenever a certain "li" is clicked. So far, it's not working for me. Here's some of the code that I have:

```
    <ul>
        <li id="a">A) Lucy</li>
        <li id="b">B) Bonnie</li>
        <li id="c">C) Sheila</li>
        <li id="d">D) Kai</li>
    </ul>
```

This is the Jquery that I'm using to try to add a class to it.

```
      $( "ul li #a" ).click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('correct');
      });
```

Comment: The selector should be `$( "ul li#a" )` or `$( "ul #a" )`

Comment: If it has an ID you should just select directly with `$("#a")`.

Comment: Thank you guys but for some reason, it's not working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close-- you simply had a space between the selector and the id:

- `li#a` means "an li with an id of 'a'"
- `li #a` means "some element with an id of 'a' that's inside of an li".

```js
$( "ul li#a" ).click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('correct');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="a">A) Lucy</li>
    <li id="b">B) Bonnie</li>
    <li id="c">C) Sheila</li>
    <li id="d">D) Kai</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#a").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('correct');
});
```

```css
.correct{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="a">A) Lucy</li>
  <li id="b">B) Bonnie</li>
  <li id="c">C) Sheila</li>
  <li id="d">D) Kai</li>
</ul>
```

for li #a meaning child of li with ID a but li has the id a so better yet use $("#a")

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li #a
```

looks for an element with id "a" that is a child of li. You need:

```
ul li#a
```